# ios - possible memory leaks with nsmutablearray not deleted?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, memory-leaks, nsmutablearray

I'm new to iOS development and in my app I'm seeing some strange memory usage behavior.

I'm getting objects from server in such `setupDataForPage` method:

```
- (void)setupDataForPage:(int)page actionType:(NSString *)type success:(void (^)())callback 
{
__weak MyTableViewController *weakSelf = self;

// clearing image cache because feed contains a lot of images
[[SDImageCache sharedImageCache] clearMemory];
[[SDImageCache sharedImageCache] clearDisk];

MyHTTPClient *API = [MyHTTPClient new];

[API feedFor:page success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id data) {
    NSArray *data = [data objectForKey:@"data"];

    if ([data count] > 0) {
        // remove all objects to refresh with new ones
        if ([type isEqualToString:@"pullToRefresh"]) {
            [weakSelf.models removeAllObjects];
        }

        // populate data
        NSMutableArray *result = [NSMutableArray new];
        for (NSDictionary *modelData in data) {
            MyModel *model = [[MyModel alloc] initWithDictionary:modelData];
            [result addObject:model];
        }

        [weakSelf.models addObjectsFromArray:result];
        [weakSelf.tableView reloadData];
    }

    callback();
} failure:nil];
}
```

it is used in **viewDidLoad** while getting initial request and also for pull refresh and infinite scrolling:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

__block int page = 1;
__weak MyTableViewController *weakSelf = self;

// initial load
[self setupDataForPage:page actionType:@"initial" success:^{ page += 1; }];

// pull to refresh
[self.tableView addPullToRefreshWithActionHandler:^{
    [weakSelf setupDataForPage:1 actionType:@"pullToRefresh" success:^{
        [weakSelf.tableView.pullToRefreshView stopAnimating];
    }];
}];

// infinite scrolling
[self.tableView addInfiniteScrollingWithActionHandler:^{
    [weakSelf setupItemsForPage:page actionType:@"infiniteScroll" success:^{
        page += 1;
        [weakSelf.tableView.infiniteScrollingView stopAnimating];
    }];
}];
}
```

I noticed that even after pull to refresh action which returns the same data (and I'm just removing all models and add them once more) my app's memory usage grows from nearly `19mb` to `24mb`..

I would like someone more experienced to look at this piece of code to determine whether it contains some possible memory leaks.. Should I somehow delete `NSMutableArray *result` variable after assigning it to models array?

Thanks!

Comment: This may be because in every *pullToRefresh* you are allocating and initializing a new array.

Comment: @Morpheus is ARC removing it?

Comment: Instead of using `new` array, try to add objects in *weakSelf.models*. in *for-in* loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, use `@autoreleasepool` here:

```
@autoreleasepool {
    NSArray *data = [data objectForKey:@"data"];

    if ([data count] > 0) {
        // remove all objects to refresh with new ones
        if ([type isEqualToString:@"pullToRefresh"]) {
            [weakSelf.models removeAllObjects];
        }

        // populate data
        NSMutableArray *result = [NSMutableArray new];
        for (NSDictionary *modelData in data) {
            MyModel *model = [[MyModel alloc] initWithDictionary:modelData];
            [result addObject:model];
        }

        [weakSelf.models addObjectsFromArray:result];
        [weakSelf.tableView reloadData];
    }
}
```

`@autoreleasepool` allows you to release every object allocated in that scope **IMMEDIATELY**.

This is perfect situation where use it ;)

Comment: this is your code, with just in more the @autoreleasepool { opened and closed at the end...what is the problem?

Comment: I mean just inside ``[API feedFor:page success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id data) { ...`` ?

Comment: Okay :) added, looks like it helped a bit, after pullToRefresh memory increased by 1Mb now, but still increasing.. could ``NSMutableArray *result = [NSMutableArray new];`` be the cause of it?

Comment: No this is normal because you add ever new data to your general array, and never remove it, so new data, increase memory, completely normal :) . If my answer work, please don't forget to select the best answer. Thanks man.

Comment: Thanks! Btw is ``@autoreleasepool`` really necessary for me 'cause my app is using ARC?

Comment: autoreleasepool is necessary when you are allocating many data but you want release it immediately. ARC or NO-ARC. ;)